# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.getFcmToken')

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

How to get `fcm token` from `firebase` in `react-native` . Currently I am using these packages

```
@react-native-firebase/app
@react-native-firebase/messaging
```

my code

```
const RegisterScreen = (props) => {
  const [fcmToken, setfcmToken] = useState();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    
    messaging()
    .getToken()
    .then(token => {
      return saveTokenToDatabase(token);
    });
 
  }, []);
async function saveTokenToDatabase(token) {
  
  console.log(token)
}
}
```

I want to get fcm token from firebase when any user register in react native but it gives me that error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.getFcmToken')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to rewrite the code like this:

```js
const RegisterScreen = async (props) => {
  const [fcmToken, setfcmToken] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    messaging()
      .getToken()
      .then((token) => {
        return setfcmToken(token);
      });
  }, []);

  async function saveTokenToDatabase(token) {
    console.log(token);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (fcmToken) {
      saveTokenToDatabase(fcmToken);
    }
  }, [fcmToken]);
};
```

From your error message it looks like you try to get the `token` from `this`. You either habe an issue with `async/await` where you try to get it before you set it or an issue with `useEffect` where you also coult try to get it before it is set to the state. I'm also not sure where to you want to use `this` in a react function. They don't have `this`.